# Reload data when change the ng-view and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm a newbie in angular.

I have this module

```
    var uhuhapp = angular.module('uhuhapp',
['ngRoute','textAngular','ui.bootstrap',
'ngAnimate','ngCookies','720kb.socialshare']);

uhuhapp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'folders',
    controller: 'FoldersController',
  })
   .when('/folder/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'documents',
    controller: 'DocumentsController',
  })
   .when('/documents', {
    templateUrl: 'documents',
    controller: 'DocumentsController',

  })
   .when('/newdocument', {
    templateUrl: 'document',
    controller: 'NewDocumentController',
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

Well, If I create a new item in "/newdocument", when I navigate to another route, for example "/documents", there is not showing the new item in the ng-repeat, I have to reload.

**There is the controller for "/newdocument":**

```
    uhuhapp.controller('NewDocumentController',
['$scope','$http','folderService','documentService',
function($scope, $http, folderService, documentService){

  folderService.success(function(folders){
    $scope.folders = folders;
  });

  $scope.newDocumentData = {};

  $scope.createDocument = function(){
      $http.post('/api/documents', $scope.newDocumentData)
          .success(function(document) {
            $scope.newDocumentData = document;
          })
          .error(function(document) {
            console.log('Error:' + document);
          });
        };

    $scope.updateDocument = function(id){
        $http.put('/api/documents/' + id, $scope.newDocumentData)
            .success(function(document) {
              $scope.newDocumentData = document;
            })
            .error(function(document) {
              console.log('Error:' + document);
            });
          };

}]);
```

**and the controller for /documents:**

```
    uhuhapp.controller('DocumentsController',
['$http','$scope','documentService', '$routeParams','$rootScope',
function($http, $scope, documentService, $routeParams,$rootScope){

  documentService.success(function(documents){

        $scope.documents = documents;
  });

}]);
```

What I have to do for upgrading the data in the controller (for example "DocumentsController") when I create a new item in the database and I navigate to another route (for example "/documents")?

I am using the same service in both controllers "documentService":

```
uhuhapp.factory('documentService',['$http',function($http){
  return $http.get('/api/documents')
    .success(function(data){
      return data;
    })
    .error(function(err){
      return err;
    });
}]);
```

I see something about digest, apply, watch and resolve promises, but I have not idea how can use them in my app.

Thank you.

Comment: can you verify `documentService.success(function(documents){...});` is running every time you visit the route and `documents` actually has data? If you're wondering about digest, apply etc try `$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.documents = documents});`

Comment: @Ronnie Hello, thank you. The documentService is not running when I return to /documents route. Is only running the very first time.

Where I have to put the apply?

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

So your service is only running once when you go back to `/documents` I had a similar problem on one of my apps. Try listening for the routeChangeSuccess event

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current)
{ 
  documentService.success(function(documents)
  {
    $scope.documents = documents;
  });
});
```

You will need to include `$rootScope` in your controller's dependencies. Another way to do it is to setup a `broadcast` event and you can listen for custom events like:

`$rootScope.$broadcast('reloadDocuments');` //-- broadcast your custom event

&

`$scope.$on('reloadDocuments', function(){...});`
//-- listen for your event and in the function, run your `documentService` call

Comment: Hello again, **Thank you, now the service is running** but Is not loading the new data. I create a new item, but If I not reload the page the new item is not in the json that brings the service.

Comment: ok so next step would be to verify what the data looks like. In the `success` function, do a `console.log(documents)`. What do those results look like?

Comment: Yes, I did it, there is all the items but not the new item. This is the process: 1. I create a new item in /newdocument (controller: NewDocumentController) 2.then I go to /documents (controller:DocumentsController (where I put your '$routeChangeSuccess' solution)) and there is all the items in the ng-repeat, but no the new one (I log the documents too, and is loading all the items but not the new one). If I reload the page, then appears the new item.

Comment: so when you `console.log(documents)` (in your routeChangeSuccess event) after you've created a new one, it isn't showing the new item? Do you have caching enabled?

Comment: It isn't showing the new item when I go to /documents route, but is showing in the /newdocument route.

Comment: that is odd since you're making a new call to the documentService. It sounds like the get request is cached. In your config block, add the dependeny: `$httpProvider` and set these default headers: `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';` and `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';`

Comment: How I add that to the config? I already have the routes uhuhapp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider... Where I put the $httpProvider?

Comment: you can add more to your config. Place it above or below your route definitions. Be sure to inject the provider: `uhuhapp.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) { ...});`

Comment: @Ronnie is right this should do the trick the weird part is that if you havent set cache to true it shouldnt cache anything.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it by resolve everytime you get to the documents view

```
.when('/documents', {
    templateUrl: 'documents',
    controller: 'DocumentsController',
    resolve:{
        document: function(documentService){
          return documentService.success(function(documents)
          {
            return documents;
          });
        }
    }    
})
```

and in your controller

```
 uhuhapp.controller('DocumentsController',
['$http','$scope','documentService', 'document', '$routeParams','$rootScope',
function($http, $scope, documentService,document, $routeParams,$rootScope){
   $scope.documents = document;                               
}]);
```

if in service your $http.get documents have cache to true turn it to false

ok try this in your controller to see if anything from the call has been cached.

```
var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
var get = cache.get('/api/documents');
console.log(get);
```

Comment: Thank you! how I turn cache to false? return $http.get('/api/documents',  { cache: false}) Is not working, are not showing the new items.

Comment: I did $scope.documents = document.data; becasue only document brings a big object with another things and the items are in an array named data.

Comment: ok i didnt know how you handle your data in your service.$http.get('api/documents',{cache:false}) should do the trick.Im updating my answer.

Comment: i dont see any other problem in your code it should fetch the new data every time you get in the documents view.

Comment: It's no fetching the new data, maybe a mistake when I create the new item? I have to reload or watch or something?

Comment: no from what i see you create the new document just fine and when you go to the /documents it should send the get request and get the data again everytime you go to that view.The only other problem would be if you had set cache to true and you should set it to false or update the cache.When you submit the new document you go back to the /documents view with some button or something?

Comment: no, just a link in the menu href="#/documents". The new document is a text, when you save, the api returns the same document and fills the ng-model for continue editing the text. But the new object, when you save, is in the database, I can see it in robomongo. (I'm using mongoose)

Comment: try adding this in the bottom of your post function just for a test   $location.path('/documents');    and tell me if that updates the data.

Comment: It is redirecting to /documents, but there is no the new item in the json. I have to reload for see the new item.

Comment: i dont know where is your problem  try to look if you cache your data in the backend or something,or try to put a console.log under the get function to see if it beign called every time you go to /documents if not you have some problem in your controller.